# Cannot override a method that returns a Task<T?>

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Consider the following code:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual Task<T?> M<T>()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override Task<T?> M<T>()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This will not compile, with the following error:

`CS0508: 'B.M<T>()': return type must be 'Task<T?>' to match overridden member 'A.M<T>()'`

However, if `A` was an interface a similar code would compile with no error.
The issue does not seem to be specific to a particular version of C#.

What is the reason behind that?

Comment: You stopped reading too early, the second error you get is `error CS0453: The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable<T>'` which describes precisely both the problem and the solution.

Comment: @Blindy I've seen that error too, but that does not clarify much the issue for me. The weirdest thing is that it compiles if the method does not override another one. I can't understand why it is illegal only when overriding.

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the `abstract` modifier and to introduce an implementation of the method that does not generate a compile error. Only the overridden version is in cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Nullable reference types introduced some impedance mismatches into the language, *particularly* with respect to generics.

This is to do with nullable reference types. Before nullable reference types existed, this code wouldn't compile at all, because `T?` wouldn't be meaningful.

I don't *think* you can define this in a way that makes sense for both `T`-as-a-reference-type and `T`-as-a-value-type (unless the notnull/default version at the bottom does that)... but if you choose which of those you want, you can constrain `T` appropriately:

Constraining T to be a non-nullable value type:

```cs
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract Task<T?> M<T>() where T : struct;
}

public class B : A
{
    public override Task<T?> M<T>() where T : struct
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Constraining T to be a reference type:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract Task<T?> M<T>() where T : class;
}

public class B : A
{
    public override Task<T?> M<T>() where T : class
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I do agree it's weird - and it gets even weirder with the `notnull` constraint, where you need to specify the `default` constraint on the override:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract Task<T?> M<T>() where T : notnull;
}

public class B : A
{
    public override Task<T?> M<T>() where T : default
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I'll readily admit I don't fully understand what that means, unfortunately. The whole topic is *really* confusing...

Comment: If you want added weirdness (or reduced, depending on your point of view): if the constraint in the base class is `T : struct`, you are not required to repeat it in the derived class, as `T?` then already unambiguously specifies `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Fun indeed. Will leave that as a comment rather than add it to the answer :)

Comment: The reason why `task` has the type it does could be a question on its own, as it's a combination of two separate things -- `var` declarations being nullable regardless of the type of the expression they're taking (this is a deliberate design choice to allow reassigning them without warning), and `notnull` with a value type being just shorthand for that value type itself, since it's not involving `Nullable`. (This also makes `default` a little more logical, as `null` truly is not a legal value in this case, but `default` is.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Ooh, you're right, I hadn't taken `var` into account there. I think it's probably best to scrub that final part to avoid even more confusion.

Comment: This confusion will all be cleared up as soon as the C# designers invent a time machine, at which point they'll go back to make nullable types part of the language from version 1. (And buy a winning lottery ticket to celebrate, probably.)